# If integer look like this `010` is first 0 consider integer?

Tags: c#

There was misunderstanding about this `int number =  010`, What I am saying is

> first 0 is not integer  due to c# has no leading zero so `010` will be `10`

however one of stackoverflow user saying

> first 0 in `010` is integer

so could anyone help to explain in details why first `0` in `010` is integer even though it has no value or it doesn't represent any mathematical integer !

thanks in advance

Comment: If you're making a `integer literal` then all leading zeros are ignored. What post were you referring to, were they talking about binary format?

Comment: A zero is an integer; but `010` has the same binary representation inside a computer as `10`, so they cannot be distinguished (unless they are strings).  If you use an integer with leading zeroes, they will be ignored as they have no representation.

Comment: Good question, I could have explained it in the last post, but was irrelevant to your answer you removed ;)

Comment: @gunr2171 it is about integer format

Comment: @Amy, exactly, that what I am saying ..thanks for clearing my doubts

Comment: to write  literal in C# there  three possibility       for decimal  you can write  010 or 10. both are equval . but if you want  octal then you have to write 0x10.    in C/C++ there  is  differnce between 10 and 010.   10 is for decimal and 010 for octal

Answer (score 2):

When you are writing integer literals, leading zeros don't mean anything.

```
var a = 10;
var b = 010;

a == b // true
```

It's not that the "first 0 is not [an] integer", it's that the leading 0 is ignored, because it doesn't contribute any information to the value of the number.

The same is with binary notation - leading zeros do not increase the information of the number (except for maybe the storage size of the value, but that's meta-information).

If you're dealing with *strings*, that's a whole different ballgame, as `"010"` has a different character array than `"10"`, even if they *parse* to the same integer value.

```
var c = "010"
var d = "10"

c == d // false
int.Parse(c) == int.Parse(d) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so obviously 0 is an integer and you can do the math on a 0. `0*1 = 0` for example. When looking at what your computer sees from an integer standpoint you'll notice that 010 and 10 both have the same binary representation. So that begs the question, why is 0 being ignored? Remember that computers understand instructions, one... at... a... time. Meaning that when it first reads through that integer, even with math, it starts at the first character and goes through. The only other difference is strings or other data types that may make better use of that 0.

#### Binary Representation of 10

> 1010

#### Binary Representation of 010

> 1010

Now since we recognize that computers read one instruction at a time, if it is given a `0` (Which has a binary representation of `0`) what happens when that instruction has any math completed on it? Nothing is what happens. `0*100=0` or `0/2=0` the difference being addition or subtraction which takes your integer into positive or negative value. `0+100=100` now if you look at the instructions it again starts with the `0` and then it's cleaned out leaving you with the binary representation of whatever had some calculation.